# Ace Editor Load new content Dynamically Clear old content with New one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor, html-editor

I am loading a Html content in Text editor using Ace Editor where the user edits and saves content of his own. So the user can exit and open a new HTML . What is procedure to clear old content and load new content.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 8):

If you want to completely discard old content, and clear undo history use

```
editor.session.setValue(text)
```

If you want to keep old content to restore it later, e.g. for tabs, use

```
newSession = ace.createEditSession(text, mode/*optional*/)
var oldSession = editor.session
editor.setSession(newSession)
// to restore old state call editor.setSession(oldSession)
```